# Spring boot 1.4.2.RELEASE error on startup java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.beans.factory.ObjectProvider

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-bean

I am trying to upgrade spring-boot from 1.3 to `1.4.2.RELEASE`. Running `mvn spring-boot:run` throws the following error.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.jpaVendorAdapter
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:64) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:102) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForBeanMethod(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:178) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:140) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:116) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:333) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:243) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:273) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:98) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:678) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:520) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1186) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1175) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at com.cisco.ple.AdminApplication.main(AdminApplication.java:20) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_74]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_74]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_74]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_74]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: @ConditionalOnMissingBean did not specify a bean using type, name or annotation and the attempt to deduce the bean's type failed
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$BeanSearchSpec.validate(OnBeanCondition.java:310) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$BeanSearchSpec.<init>(OnBeanCondition.java:300) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchOutcome(OnBeanCondition.java:112) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:47) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$BeanTypeDeductionException: Failed to deduce bean type for org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.jpaVendorAdapter
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$BeanSearchSpec.addDeducedBeanTypeForBeanMethod(OnBeanCondition.java:373) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$BeanSearchSpec.addDeducedBeanType(OnBeanCondition.java:347) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$BeanSearchSpec.<init>(OnBeanCondition.java:294) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/beans/factory/ObjectProvider
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_74]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701) ~[na:1.8.0_74]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975) ~[na:1.8.0_74]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:609) ~[spring-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:521) ~[spring-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:507) ~[spring-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$BeanSearchSpec.addDeducedBeanTypeForBeanMethod(OnBeanCondition.java:360) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    ... 26 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.beans.factory.ObjectProvider
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_74]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_74]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331) ~[na:1.8.0_74]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_74]
    ... 33 common frames omitted

2016-11-16 15:10:44.540  INFO 62059 --- [  restartedMain] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@4fefe49d: startup date [Wed Nov 16 15:10:40 IST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-11-16 15:10:44.541  WARN 62059 --- [  restartedMain] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception thrown from LifecycleProcessor on context close

java.lang.IllegalStateException: LifecycleProcessor not initialized - call 'refresh' before invoking lifecycle methods via the context: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@4fefe49d: startup date [Wed Nov 16 15:10:40 IST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getLifecycleProcessor(AbstractApplicationContext.java:415) [spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:975) [spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:934) [spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:818) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:326) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1186) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1175) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at com.cisco.ple.AdminApplication.main(AdminApplication.java:20) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_74]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_74]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_74]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_74]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]

Exception in thread "restartedMain" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/beans/factory/ObjectProvider
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:609)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:521)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:534)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:507)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:567)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:683)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:627)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:597)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1445)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:445)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:415)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:530)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:523)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeansOfType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1162)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getExitCodeFromMappedException(SpringApplication.java:886)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getExitCodeFromException(SpringApplication.java:872)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleExitCode(SpringApplication.java:858)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:812)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:326)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1186)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1175)
    at com.cisco.ple.AdminApplication.main(AdminApplication.java:20)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.beans.factory.ObjectProvider
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 30 more
```

Here is the `mvn dependency:tree` output

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.10:tree (default-cli) @ Admin ---
[INFO] company:admin:war:1.0
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:jar:1.4.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:1.4.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:1.4.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.1.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.1.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.21:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.21:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.17:runtime
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator:jar:1.4.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:1.4.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.2.4.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.3.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:jar:1.4.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:jar:1.4.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc:jar:8.5.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-juli:jar:8.5.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.0.11.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.20.0-GA:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss:jandex:jar:2.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:5.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:5.0.11.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.transaction:javax.transaction-api:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:1.10.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:1.12.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:4.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:4.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:jar:1.4.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:4.1.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:4.1.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:jar:1.4.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.8.9:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail:jar:1.4.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:4.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.sun.mail:javax.mail:jar:1.5.6:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-velocity:jar:1.4.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.9.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:2.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.velocity:velocity:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.velocity:velocity-tools:jar:2.0:compile
[INFO] |     +- commons-chain:commons-chain:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |     +- oro:oro:jar:2.0.8:compile
[INFO] |     +- sslext:sslext:jar:1.2-0:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.apache.struts:struts-core:jar:1.3.8:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.apache.struts:struts-taglib:jar:1.3.8:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.apache.struts:struts-tiles:jar:1.3.8:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-cache:jar:1.4.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-redis:jar:1.4.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-redis:jar:1.7.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-keyvalue:jar:1.1.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-oxm:jar:4.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.21:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.21:compile
[INFO] +- redis.clients:jedis:jar:2.8.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.commons:commons-pool2:jar:2.4.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security.oauth:spring-security-oauth2:jar:2.0.12.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:4.1.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools:jar:1.4.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:1.4.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:1.4.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:1.4.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:1.4.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:jar:1.4.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- junit:junit:jar:4.12:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:2.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:1.10.19:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.1:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:jar:1.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.json:json:jar:20140107:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:4.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:1.4.2.RELEASE:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:8.5.6:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:8.5.6:provided
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:8.5.6:provided
[INFO] +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper:jar:8.5.6:provided
[INFO] |  \- org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler:ecj:jar:4.5.1:provided
[INFO] +- jstl:jstl:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-taglibs:jar:4.1.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-acl:jar:4.1.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.0.4:compile
[INFO] +- cglib:cglib-nodep:jar:2.2:compile
[INFO] +- net.sf.ehcache:ehcache-core:jar:2.6.0:compile
[INFO] +- net.sf.json-lib:json-lib:jar:jdk15:2.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.5:compile
[INFO] |  \- net.sf.ezmorph:ezmorph:jar:1.0.6:compile
[INFO] +- com.googlecode.ehcache-spring-annotations:ehcache-spring-annotations:jar:1.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] +- javax.mail:mail:jar:1.4.5:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-core:jar:3.1.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.woodstox:woodstox-core-asl:jar:4.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.ws.xmlschema:xmlschema-core:jar:2.2.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws:jar:3.1.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- xml-resolver:xml-resolver:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.0.4:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-transports-http:jar:3.1.5:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs:jar:3.1.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-ws-security:jar:3.1.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-security-saml:jar:3.1.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-security:jar:3.1.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.sf.ehcache:ehcache:jar:2.10.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.wss4j:wss4j-policy:jar:2.1.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.wss4j:wss4j-ws-security-stax:jar:2.1.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.wss4j:wss4j-bindings:jar:2.1.4:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.wss4j:wss4j-ws-security-policy-stax:jar:2.1.4:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.wss4j:wss4j-ws-security-common:jar:2.1.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.santuario:xmlsec:jar:2.0.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.opensaml:opensaml-saml-impl:jar:3.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.opensaml:opensaml-profile-api:jar:3.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.opensaml:opensaml-core:jar:3.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.opensaml:opensaml-saml-api:jar:3.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.opensaml:opensaml-xmlsec-api:jar:3.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.opensaml:opensaml-soap-api:jar:3.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.opensaml:opensaml-security-impl:jar:3.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.opensaml:opensaml-security-api:jar:3.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- org.cryptacular:cryptacular:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:jar:1.51:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.opensaml:opensaml-xmlsec-impl:jar:3.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- net.shibboleth.utilities:java-support:jar:7.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:18.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.9.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.opensaml:opensaml-xacml-impl:jar:3.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.opensaml:opensaml-xacml-api:jar:3.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.opensaml:opensaml-xacml-saml-impl:jar:3.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.opensaml:opensaml-xacml-saml-api:jar:3.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jasypt:jasypt:jar:1.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec:jar:1.7.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.wss4j:wss4j-ws-security-dom:jar:2.1.4:compile
[INFO] +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.10:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-rs-extension-providers:jar:3.1.5:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-bindings-soap:jar:3.1.5:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-bindings-xml:jar:3.1.5:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb:jar:3.1.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.2.11:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-core:jar:2.2.11:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-frontend-simple:jar:3.1.5:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-ws-policy:jar:3.1.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- wsdl4j:wsdl4j:jar:1.6.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.neethi:neethi:jar:3.0.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-ws-addr:jar:3.1.5:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-rs-client:jar:3.1.5:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-wsdl:jar:3.1.5:compile
[INFO] +- javax.ws.rs:jsr311-api:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.0:compile
[INFO] +- commons-validator:commons-validator:jar:1.4.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.tiles:tiles-servlet:jar:3.0.4:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.tiles:tiles-request-servlet:jar:1.0.4:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.tiles:tiles-core:jar:3.0.4:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.tiles:tiles-jsp:jar:3.0.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tiles:tiles-template:jar:3.0.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.tiles:tiles-autotag-core-runtime:jar:1.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.tiles:tiles-request-jsp:jar:1.0.4:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.tiles:tiles-api:jar:3.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.tiles:tiles-request-api:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] +- mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:5.1.40:compile
[INFO] +- org.antlr:stringtemplate:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] +- org.owasp.esapi:esapi:jar:2.0GA:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-configuration:commons-configuration:jar:1.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils-core:jar:1.7.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.16:compile
[INFO] |  +- xom:xom:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- xerces:xmlParserAPIs:jar:2.6.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- xalan:xalan:jar:2.7.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- jaxen:jaxen:jar:1.1.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.beanshell:bsh-core:jar:2.0b4:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.owasp.antisamy:antisamy:jar:1.4.3:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-css:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-ext:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-util:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- xml-apis:xml-apis-ext:jar:1.3.04:compile
[INFO] |     \- net.sourceforge.nekohtml:nekohtml:jar:1.9.22:compile
[INFO] +- javax.inject:javax.inject:jar:1:compile
[INFO] +- xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.9.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.4.01:compile
[INFO] +- org.codehaus.jettison:jettison:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- stax:stax-api:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.opencsv:opencsv:jar:3.7:compile
[INFO] +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:jar:1.17.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-client:jar:1.17.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.sun.jersey.contribs:jersey-multipart:jar:1.17.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.jvnet:mimepull:jar:1.6:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.session:spring-session:jar:1.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.8.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.8.4:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.8.4:compile
[INFO] +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml:jar:2.8.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jaxb-annotations:jar:2.8.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:jar:3.1.4:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml.woodstox:woodstox-core:jar:5.0.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-hateoas:jar:1.4.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.hateoas:spring-hateoas:jar:0.20.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.plugin:spring-plugin-core:jar:1.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.2.0:test
[INFO] |  \- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.2.1:test
[INFO] |     \- net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:1.1:test
[INFO] +- org.jolokia:jolokia-core:jar:1.3.5:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.jsoup:jsoup:jar:1.9.2:compile
[INFO] \- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.5:compile
```

It looks like class **org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.jpaVendorAdapter** of artifact *org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:1.4.2.RELEASE* is using class **org.springframework.beans.factory.ObjectProvider** of artifact *org.springframework:spring-beans*. However [**org.springframework.beans.factory.ObjectProvider**](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/ObjectProvider.html) was added only after version `4.3` of the artifact and `provided` version of the artifact is `4.2.4.RELEASE` in the spring boot parent. Version `1.4.2.RELEASE` is supposed to be a stable version of spring-boot.

What's wrong with the configuration?

Comment: Even Spring Boot 1.4.1.RELEASE depends on Spring Framework 4.3.3 (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/1.4.1.RELEASE). Are you sure you don't have an older version of Spring Beans as a transitive dependency somehwere?

Comment: @RafalG. I added dependency tree output, but I am unable to understand which dependency is responsible for locking the transitive dependency.

Comment: I can see that Spring Boot 1.4.2.RELEASE has somewhat weird dependencies specified on Maven Central. Can you please try to downgrade to 1.4.1.RELEASE ?

Comment: @RafalG. I tried downgrading to `1.4.1.RELEASE` with same result. `1.4.2.RELEASE` is supposed to be stable version, so it would be better than `1.4.1.RELEASE`. Could you upvote the question so that it surfaces on top of the results?

Comment: Can you show me your dependencies once you downgrade to 1.4.1?

Comment: @RafalG. here it is http://pastebin.com/ttCG13JR

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128250/discussion-between-rafal-g-and-juzer-ali).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is: 
Ali uses a few dependency management plugins in his pom.xml and has a 4.2.4.RELEASE property defined. This property is used by one of these plugins to determine which versions of JARs should be downloaded.

In his scenario, he has to remember to upgrade both  and version of 'spring-boot-starter-parent' to compatible releases.

Answer (score 0):

To expand what @Rafal G. said, I had a property defined in my `pom.xml` `<spring.version>4.2.4.RELEASE</spring.version>`. Same property is defined in spring boot parent pom.xml, and my explicit declaration of this property was overriding the one mentioned in spring-boot's parent pom.

Another reason why you should keep your `pom.xml` clean.